# grep to match a certain number sequence in a mix of text and numbers

Tags: regex, r, grepl

I have several files similar to "PRISM_ppt_stable_4kmM2_------_bil.bil", where ------ is a year and month, like 190112. The file date ranges from 189501 to 198012. In R, on a Windows 7 machine, I would like to match all the files for the time from 192001 to 193912. I'm pretty sure I want `grepl()`, but I can't figure out the way to refer to the sequence in the command. I tried

```
my.files[grepl('PRISM.*/1920/.bil$',my.files)]
```

and

```
my.files[grepl('PRISM.*[1][9][2][0].',my.files)]
```

and other variations, but just get error messages. I know that [0-9]{4} will match any four number sequence, but that would match all the files.

Comment: `(189[5-9]|1[9]([0-7][0-9]|80))(0[1-9]|1[0-2])` try this regex.

Comment: @AruneshSingh thanks for suggestion. That would cover all the files/dates. I was looking for a smaller set of dates, but I was able to use your reply to find what I wanted. `my.files[grepl('(192[0-9]|193[0-9])(0[1-9]|1[0-2])',my.files)]`

Comment: Lol , sorry I thought you want to match from `1895` to `1980`, for that indeed it is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I'd do:

```
# Reproducible example of file list
library(stringr)
ym <- paste0(1895:1980, str_pad(1:12, 2, pad='0'))
file_list <- paste0("PRISM_ppt_stable_4kmM2_", ym, "_bil.bil")

# Create a list of desired dates and convert to your date format
dates <- seq(as.Date('1920-01-01'), as.Date('1939-12-01'), by='month')
dates <- format(dates, '%Y%m')

# Subset the file list
your_files <- file_list[str_extract(file_list, '[0-9]{6}') %in% dates]
```

Comment: A new package to check out. It didn't occur to me to use dates. Date objects still give me problems.